# Wordpress permissions issue when updating plugins

Tags: wordpress, upload, permissions, file-permissions

A Wordpress blog I maintain has recently started being unable to update plugins due to a permissions issue. Unfortunately, I don't know what has changed to cause it. I've been trying to work out the correct way to resolve the problem, but my knowledge is sadly lacking.

WHM is configured to use PHP 5 Handler: dso

If I add this into one of my PHP files

```
echo exec( 'groups' );
```

The output is `nobody`

All folders are set to 755 permissions. When I SSL to the server the owner is the FTP owner for all folders under `public_html`.

If I type `groups` into an SSH window, the user belongs to these groups:

```
root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel
```

I keep reading different ways of resolving the problem, but I know enough to be scared by these (for example, change all folders to 777). Should I add the user to the nobody group, change the public_html folder to be owned by nobody etc...? All of these options seem incorrect to me, but I don't know enough.

Comment: I know that on apache servers the group owner should be apache. Well the owner of anything but your theme should be apache. So you can try with `chgrp -R apache www/` when you're in the `/var` folder. Also change the owner to apache `chmod -R apache:apache www/`, and then change the owner of the  `themes` folder back to you (whatever your username is). And set the permissions to 755, except for `uploads` folder. Set that permission to 766.
This worked for me when I had issues with it.

Answer (score 0):

A Wordpress blog I maintain has recently started being unable to update plugins due to a permissions issue. Unfortunately, I don't know what has changed to cause it. I've been trying to work out the correct way to resolve the problem, but my knowledge is sadly lacking.

WHM is configured to use PHP 5 Handler: dso

If I add this into one of my PHP files

echo exec( 'groups' );
The output is nobody

All folders are set to 755 permissions. When I SSL to the server the owner is the FTP owner for all folders under public_html.

If I type groups into an SSH window, the user belongs to these groups:

root bin daemon sys adm disk wheel

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).